# Looking to confirm correct OID to poll for Nexus power module operational status and the meaning of results

Tags: snmp, cisco-nexus-7k

The OID I am polling at the moment is cefcModuleOperStatus 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.117.1.2.1.1.2. When I poll a Nexus 7k switch I am getting a result: 2,2. I am guessing this means OK and OK. The thing is I don't know what other outputs there are for this OID and what there values might mean. I am guessing I'm correct in assuming that the values 2,2 mean OK, OK because I logged on to the switch and saw that both power modules were in OK state

Why are OID's so opaque?! I can't find any decent documentation which gives a full thorough explanation of what each non intuitively named OID might mean and how to interpret the results. So frustrating!

Anyway does anybody know if this is indeed the correct OID to poll? and if so are you aware of the possible out puts and what the nemerical values returned might translate to eg. 0 = absent, 1 = failed, 2 = OK?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cisco's [SNMP Object Navigator](http://snmp.cloudapps.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en) is a great resource to answer most of these questions.

Entering your OID gives the following, so indeed 2 = OK :

```
Object  cefcModuleOperStatus
OID     1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.117.1.2.1.1.2
Type    ModuleOperType 

        1:unknown
        2:ok
        3:disabled
        4:okButDiagFailed
        5:boot
        6:selfTest
        7:failed
        8:missing
        9:mismatchWithParent
        10:mismatchConfig
        11:diagFailed
        12:dormant
        13:outOfServiceAdmin
        14:outOfServiceEnvTemp
        15:poweredDown
        16:poweredUp
        17:powerDenied
        18:powerCycled
        19:okButPowerOverWarning
        20:okButPowerOverCritical
        21:syncInProgress
        22:upgrading
        23:okButAuthFailed
        24:mdr
        25:fwMismatchFound
        26:fwDownloadSuccess
        27:fwDownloadFailure

Permission  read-only
Status      current
MIB         CISCO-ENTITY-FRU-CONTROL-MIB 
Description This object shows the module's operational state.
```

Edit: you could also have a look at [cefcFRUPower](http://snmp.cloudapps.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.117.1.1&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true) and everything below it, for more info about the po

Comment: Thanks @hertitu Yes that's a great resource. How can I tell though if efcModuleOperStatus is actually the right OID to poll for the power module though? Short of actually pulling the power module how could I confirm? The word that throws me is 'module' I mean what 'module'?! Anyway thanks very much!

Comment: @yermander well to be very honest I'm not familiar with this particular OID or even with monitoring N7k in general, but you could have a look at the CISCO-ENTITY-FRU-CONTROL-MIB and/or do an snmpwalk of  ciscoEntityFRUControlMIB to see what further info you find there; at first sight a module can be a PSU, fan, etc. so there should be some other identifying info in that table that allows you to determine which module is which.